# How to work on more complex question where multiple iteration may necessary to clean it up

Tags: support, edits

*Background*:
Asking the right question on the right place on SO is not an easy task. On a recently deleted question I tried to find a solution that would help all parties (questioner, viewer, operator) to reduce frustration caused getting down vote on asking question. However, this is a more extensive topic that I would like to explore later.

One of the topics in the above-mentioned question, which was not debated in any way, was that we often have to work iteratively:

> I think asking the right question on the right place is often an iterative process. All of us learn step by step and the right support is essential.

Many of the question, we all face on daily basis, are pretty complex. Many of as working in a mixed environment (for me right now: Windows, WSL, docker, ubuntu, R, python, angular, TFS, bitbucket, dotnet)

It would be important to allow to start with *work in progress* question and get feedback to *incorporate* them. For that reason I would like to ask:

- How to work on more complex question where multiple iteration may necessary to clean it up and refine the complexity to acceptable level, especially if an early feedback would be appreciated?
- Is it acceptable solution to add "WIP:" flag to the question at the title to signalize "work in progress"?
- What ?rules? would be acceptable to keep a question as "work in progress"?

*Note*: Please note that I consider this topic to be "work in progress", please support it in clarifying.

Edit:
I completely agree with the sentence mentioned by @Makoto:

> The only way to get some assistance with environmental complexity is to reduce its complexity, and this is a principle that applies both internal to your project and code (with those "in the know") and externally, with complete and utter strangers.

To achieve the same acceptable level of complexity, it is often important to get feedback from viewers and review earlier posts (we need to be careful about previous posts as many bad examples are still highly valued).

Edit:
Iterative: Also the answer mentioned by @rene: [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368115/5770014) tells even for a bad question:

> A bad question should be edited to make it better, or closed. The sooner one of these things happen, the better, as less time will be wasted on bad questions.

Edit:
@rene's response suggests that a special session should be organized to deal with such topics, but in this case we may face other issues, such as:

- How to decide if a topic is important or interesting enough to start a session?
- How to involve others in preparing such a topic?

On comments:

> Are you asking a question about the site, or proposing a new feature here?

I'm not sure, possible, not necessarily. I think, I would like to get an answer/ solution that is easy for every one.

> I fear that downvotes aren't going to be the only irritating facet of this post. It's not that we don't like you, we may simply disagree with your new feature proposal.

Open for suggestion on how to change that we agree.

> What's the difference? Do we as professionals tolerate someone who comes up to us, interrupts our workflow and asks incomplete questions? We might tolerate it of someone who is younger (e.g. 5 years old) and can't fully form questions all that well, but of professionals?

We all have different threshold on how extensive explanation we require on questions. Your trainees will as good as you tutor them.

> in theory, a "WIP" question is a bad one that hasn't been made good yet...

IMO: WIP question is an incomplete question where the author shows willingness to work on it based on research by reading post suggested in comments by viewers. BAD question are abandoned ones with no singes of refinement effort on any comments.

> The way I look on this is in this way: on this site, the asker is requesting help to solve a problem, and the answer(s), volunteer their free time to give this help, and the site benefits by having a high-quality Q and A available for review by future visitors. The asker pays nothing for this service, while anyone who puts in the time to answer a question does in fact pay with "opportunity cost", the value of their time that could have been used to pursue remunerative tasks. In this situation, the onus is on the asker and the asker alone to ask as high quality a question as possible.

IMO: Both the questioner and the respondent work in their spare time, in case both parties are willing to refine their works. Even the questioner in order to reduce the complexity of the original topic to the required level needs to put significant effort.

> Did any of your school teachers let you turn in partial assignments and fill the rest in later? What about your bosses , do they not expect completed work? Why should people who review questions here not expect them to be complete enough to fully understand the specific problem and attempts made to solve that problem? You are trying to sell a concept that just won't work. You are only thinking from perspective of someone asking...try to think about it as a reviewer of an incomplete question also. Few want to or will spend the time to ask enough questions to extract incomplete detail.

There is a fine line here. There is final submission and there are consultation sessions. There is task deadline and there are work meetings. etc. Please don't mix them.

> The task deadline is when you hit send to post the question. "Consultation sessions"??? , SO isn't a mentoring service it is a practical programming problem solving site with purpose of building a public knowledge base

Based on community support, provided by volunteers. Why are we so harsh on them?

Comment: Are you asking a question about the site, or proposing a new feature here?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu:  From the **tags** it looks like it could be either of them.

Comment: Is a new feature needed to use "WIP" word as flag?

Comment: Let me read it, I'm not sure. Can I ask ?you? to stop down voting, it's irritating!

Comment: I fear that downvotes aren't going to be the only irritating facet of this post.  It's not that we don't like *you*, we may simply disagree with your new feature proposal.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274881/sandbox-for-questions and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366891/a-swat-team-of-nice-ii-temporarily-show-new-questions-only-to-designated-guide

Comment: @gnat: It is different to close a bad question compared to one the is work in progress.

Comment: @minusone:  What's the difference?  Do we as professionals tolerate someone who comes up to us, interrupts our workflow and asks incomplete questions?  We might tolerate it of someone who is younger (e.g. 5 years old) and can't fully form questions all that well, but of *professionals*?

Comment: @minusone in theory, a "WIP" question is a bad one that hasn't been made good yet....

Comment: @ Makoto: No one asks you to do so. Let people explain them self that's all.

Comment: Yep @minusone, and they have the one chance do to so when they post a question.  I'm not around all day to wait for them to edit it into shape so it can be answered.  That's not how this works.

Comment: @gnat: The question/answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/5770014) is only about closing. Is is possible to get comment on and edit a closed question?

Comment: @Makoto: "Do we as professionals tolerate someone who comes up to us, interrupts our workflow and asks incomplete questions?" I'm not sure, we agree on what "professionals " means. I don't think it is "professional" to expecting that we are right all the time. To clear things up is often iterative!

Comment: @minusone:  "Professional" as in "paid to do this".  Someone who does this for a living or works in a professional software development setting.  I would've assumed that this was universal.

Comment: @Makoto: "Do we as professionals tolerate someone who comes up to us, interrupts our workflow and asks incomplete questions?" 1. no one here interrupts you, it is your choice to read some question; 2. no one reads your thoughts to find out what details you know about a particular topic. Yes, IMO it is a guess work to put the right amount of information together.

Comment: Well, @minusone that makes me wondering ...

Comment: @reno: It would be great to explore more your idea on "work in progress session"!

Comment: @Patrice: "WIP question is a bad one that hasn't been made good yet":  Let me rephrase: IMO: WIP question is an incomplete question where the author shows willingness to work on it based on research by reading post suggested in comments by viewers. BAD question are abandoned ones with no singe of refinement effort on any comments.

Comment: Consider the following: on this site, the asker is requesting help to solve a problem, and the answerer(s), volunteer their free time to give this help, and the site benefits by having a high-quality Q and A available for review by future visitors. The asker pays nothing for this service, while anyone who puts in the time to answer a question does in fact pay with "opportunity cost", the value of their time that could have been used to pursue remunerative tasks. In this situation, the onus is on the asker and the asker alone to ask as high quality a question as possible.

Comment: Bottom line: if you want me to volunteer my free time to help you, then it would be best if you ask your question clearly and well and do so at the very start.  This equation, of course, may be flipped if the asker is paying for a service, but here, they are not.

Comment: @minusone Did any of your school teachers let you turn in partial assignments and fill the rest in later? What about your bosses , do they not expect completed work? Why should people who review questions here not expect them to be complete enough to fully understand the specific problem and attempts made to solve that problem? You are trying to sell a concept that just won't work. You are only thinking from perspective of someone asking...try to think about it as a reviewer of an incomplete question also. Few want to or will spend the time to ask enough questions to extract incomplete detail

Comment: You really need to respond to comments *in the comments*. By doing it in the question, you're clogging up both the question itself and the edit history. Right now you have one page of actual question, and two pages of quotes and rebuttals.

Comment: @F1Krazy: "You really need to respond to comments in the comments." The order of the comments change based on the votes. No ones ever puts them together. Sorry.

Comment: @F1Krazy: They will close this topic anyway... There are 2x delete on it already. I'm sad about it.

Comment: @minusone "The order of the comments change based on the votes." - No, they don't. That's the case for *answers*, but it's not the case for comments, which are always sorted in chronological order. Sometimes only the top-voted comments are shown, but if someone wants the full context of a discussion, it takes two seconds to click "View all comments".

Comment: The task deadline is when you hit send to post the question. *"Consultation sessions"*??? , SO isn't a mentoring service it is a practical programming problem solving site with purpose of building a public knowledge base

Comment: @F1Krazy: It is not easy to answer to some earlier. I'm slow. Cant keep up.

Comment: *"Both the questioner and the respondent work in their spare time, in case both parties are willing to refine their works. Even the questioner in order to reduce the complexity of the original topic to the required level needs to put significant effort."* -- but ***who*** stands to gain from the efforts of the answerers? The questioner does.

Answer (score 13):

> How to work on more complex question where multiple iteration may necessary to clean it up, especially if an early feedback would be appreciated?

*This*, right here, is the problem of perception with most question askers.  It is the assumption that it is OK to ask a question that is not complete, or is not fully formed.

I'm not going to disagree that any given development environment that we work in is complex.  However, that is not complexity that Stack Overflow owns; that is the complexity that you, the OP, own.  The only way to get some assistance with environmental complexity is to *reduce* its complexity, and this is a principle that applies both internal to your project and code (with those "in the know") and *externally*, with complete and utter strangers.

There should ***never*** be a case in which it is OK to open a question and treat it as a forum for help.  We are not here to be on call to support the complexities of your environment.  If you are looking for someone to do that, surely you could post a job opening for a consultant.

Stack Overflow performs best if the questions are narrow in scope and are treated as entities unto themselves.  It's fine to have multiple questions which link to an overarching problem, but each question you ask *must* be able to stand on its own two feet once asked.  That is to say, it's fine to reference an older question or a similar question, but you can't expect answerers to be in-context to what your previous questions were that led you to this point.

Comment: I think this answer only shows the importance and the necessity of my first question! "There should **never** be a case" but it is far too often! So we need a solution! Here is the history one of your answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20877115/timeline)! It is also iterative :)

Comment: The example you reference, @minusone, is one in which the OP came with a very explicit and direct question, and I was able to provide an explicit and direct answer.  It has been refined over the years, but that's more than well within reason and expectation.  It should absolutely be the case that we're comfortable with refining answers to help provide lasting value.  The OP didn't mutate their question to suit their current in-flight tasks, nor did they look to us as a help desk to help address their every concern.  This was a reasonable question, and it received a reasonable answer.

Comment: @minusone:  Perhaps you should just hang around on the site for a few months.  Just because people *want* a help desk experience doesn't mean that we've got the bandwidth to support it.

Comment: I understand that people are complex and working with them changes the way we are less sensitive. Your people are fast and experienced like most users never will. I work more then ten years now as developer. I'm here on SO more then four years. Sill most of my post start at -5 like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63890719/how-to-use-windows-kerberos-ticket-in-wsl-and-or-docker). I was ready to move, update...

Answer (score 10):

> How to work on more complex question where multiple iteration may necessary to clean it up, especially if an early feedback would be appreciated?

You don't on Stack Overflow. But you can organize that yourself by using a Github Gist or other venues. I have used a Github Gist for specific questions on Meta, for example [this one](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/0e56d805c29f70a1f3275727a2bd4161) and [this one](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/847ba64d67de0e3f853762d146af4f8f) where I worked with the other ROs in chat on the exact wording of those posts.

> Is it acceptable solution to add "WIP:" flag to the question at the title to signalize "work in progress"?

No, we don't do meta tags on questions. A question, once posted is good to go, ready for a broad audience and answerable. If not, then the onus is on you to get that into shape first.

> What ?rules? would be acceptable to keep a question as "work in progress"?

No acceptable rules should exist. Questions (and answers for that matter) that are a work in progress are not a good fit, there is no guarantee they will ever be ready. As such incomplete, unclear questions should be closed, downvoted and deleted.

Related:

- [If a question is going to closed, can I post half answer with "Work in Progress"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400928/if-a-question-is-going-to-closed-can-i-post-half-answer-with-work-in-progress)
- [Prevent Users from editing for upto an hour as an option when posting a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368101/prevent-users-from-editing-for-upto-an-hour-as-an-option-when-posting-a-question)

Comment: "But you can organize that yourself by using a Github Gist or other venues."  How can you decide if a topic is important, interesting enough to start your essential session? How can we involve others in the preparation of such a topic?